# Expected result not working when inheriting?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, radix

EDIT!

Stupid typo of which I didn't see caused this problem. Solved now. Thankyou everyone!

Why wont my code output the cout's from each individual class?

Expected result should be Message from 1 and Message from 2?

```
class CTest
{
public:
    virtual void WriteMessage();
};
void CTest::WriteMessage()
{
}

class CMessage1 : public CTest
{
    virtual void WriteMesssage()
    {
        cout << "Message from 1" << endl;
    }
};


class CMessage2 : public CTest
{
    virtual void WriteMesssage()
    {
        cout << "Message from 2" << endl;
    }
};


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    CTest* pMessages[4];
    pMessages[0] = new CMessage1;
    pMessages[1] = new CMessage2;
    pMessages[2] = new CMessage1;
    pMessages[3] = new CMessage2;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        pMessages[i]->WriteMessage();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Do I need to create the WriteMessage virtual void for each instance of CMessage?
Like this:

```
void CMessage2::WriteMesssage()
{
cout << "Message from 2" << endl;
}
```

Comment: What behaviour do you observe?

Comment: What is actually going wrong?

Comment: Its not printing out anything in the cout from each class. As it goes through the array in the main it should output the couts from each of the different classes. 

The code runs and compiles but there is no output at all.

Comment: WrriteMessage != WriteMesssage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misspelled `WriteMessage` as `WriteMesssage` (note the 3 's'), thus it does not override the base version.

Note that using the `override` keyword (from of C++11) can help tell you when you're not overriding what you intended to.

Comment: Of course, but this should really just be a vote-to-close as "simple typo".